# cookie is different in next js after routing

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Assume there is a distinct two pages '/webview/report' '/webview/graph'
.In report index getServerSideProps we set a cookie with a key and its corrisponding value like below

```
context.res.setHeader('set-cookie', [
  `${UTIL_CONSTANTS.accessToken}=${accessToken}`,
  `${UTIL_CONSTANTS.acceptLanguage}=${
    isUndefined(acceptedLanguage) ? '' : acceptedLanguage
  }`,
  `${UTIL_CONSTANTS.timezone}=${isUndefined(timezone) ? '' : timezone}`,
]);
```

thus results as below, which set its domain and path

[image]

after routing to /webview/graph page and re-direct back to /webview/report page via router.back() function or router push function, the cookie we read is empty.
Setting the cookies path to root route which is '/' solved the issue but we still do not know the reason why it was unable to read the values by 'context.req.headers.cookie' even tho pages were sub-route of '/webview'. I couldn't find a reference of explaining this type of behavior. what causes such behavior?

Comment: Can you edit your question and you show a screenshot of the redirect response?

Comment: @jub0bs if u r fine can we zoom call a bit?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't do that.

Comment: @jub0bs cookies remains the same its just const cookies = context.req.headers.cookie; is different when requesting the report page in initial and requesting it after some redirection. the latter ones 'accessToken and timezone and acceptedLanguage' is all undefined